# How to update postgresql's jsonb field when contains return and linefeed character "\n"

Tags: json, postgresql

Very distressing problem for PostgreSQL's JSONB update!
My input json from front like this:

```
{"note":"1\n1"}
```

The json value "1\n1" contains return and linefeed character "\n".
I want to update jsonb field with the json's value,

```
update tbale set fjson=jsonb_set_lax(fjson,'{note}','"1\n1"'::jsonb)
```

but error occurs.
Please help me, how to update when the json value contains "\n".

Comment: What version of Postgres? What is the error?

Comment: PostgreSQL 13.1.

Comment: Add information to your question. Also include the error you are getting.

Comment: My Server's language is Chinese,  the error translate to English like:  type json's input grammar invalid

Comment: Try: `{note}','"1\\n1"'`

Comment: thank you. I tested : select jsonb_set_lax('{}'::jsonb,'{note}','"1\\n1"'::jsonb) #>>'{note}' , the result is right. But, the front sends {"note":"1\n1"}, I should first use {"note":"1\n1"} #>>'{note}' to get the text value as paramter to call some function, How can I get the right text value? Can you give me some advice? thank you very much.

Comment: This is `JSON` issue, it would be the same wherever you try to create/modify a `JSON` value. This is something you will need to look into on the front end, whether whatever you are using can be set up to automatically escape this and similar characters [Reserved characters](https://www.tutorialspoint.com/json_simple/json_simple_escape_characters.htm)

Comment: @ncabc "*the front[end] sends*" - please show us the function with the query that passes the dynamic value to the database. What you've shown so far is only a static query.

Comment: ok, thanks. In fact, if I use jsonb_set_lax('{}'::jsonb,'{note}', front's json #>'{note'}), it avoids to get the text value and use jsonb type directly. and it can work. I'll try to alter my function to replace the parameter's type from text to jsonb. thanks you very much.

Comment: @ncabc What is `{note}`? Are you doing some sort of string interpolation on the query? What language are you using, which postgres library?